# Concatenate one column and multiple rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm not that good in understanding the Pandas library for Python.
Maybe one of you can help me.

I have one list which represents the first column of a table and a second list representing the rows.
(first list is filled with names of a working schedule and the second list contains the shift for the day).

My intention is to join them together so that it will look like this:

```
      | Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun |
Peter |  X1 | x1  |  -  |  -  | X2  | X2  |  -  |
Jeff  |  X2 | x2  |  -  |  -  | X1  | X1  |  -  |
Max   |  -  |  -  |  X1 |  X1 |  -  |  -  |  X2 |
```

The lists would look like this:

```
list1 = [Peter, Jeff, Max]

list2 = [[x1, x1, -, -, x2, x2, -], [x2, x2, -, -, x1, x1, -], 
[-, -, x1, x1, -, -, x2]]
```

I hope that someone can help.

Comment: We need to see your sample `lists`

Answer (score 0):

Following the Pandas documentation, to create a DataFrame (see the docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)), when you have a list of columns headers and then other lists per each row you can do something like that:

```
headers = ["A", "B", "C"]
indexes = ["Peter", "Pepito", "Maria"]
rows = [
  [1, 2, 3], 
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 2]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=rows, columns=headers, index=indexes)
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer.
I also saw this, but my problem is, that the first column of the final table is in a separate list so for example:

`list1 = [Peter, Jeff, Max]

list2 = [[x1, x1, -, -, x2, x2, -], [x2, x2, -, -, x1, x1, -], [-, -, x1, x1, -, -, x2]]`

Comment: So, can you update your question adding an example of the lists you have, like the headers, the list1 you added here and the values lists?

Comment: @JNB I've updated my answer to include the indexes, which is what you are looking for with the `list1` I think.

Comment: You are welcome. Please, let me know if it works :D

Comment: Well my code looks like this: 
`table = pd.DataFrame(data=dp_data[31:], index=dp_names, columns=dp_data[:30])`

But for some reason only the first row is existing in the Frame...

Comment: Can you show us the format of the `dp_data[31:]`? It suggest me that `dp_data[31:]` is returning a list, which means will become just one row. Take into account, that in the data you have to pass a list o lists, where each list will become a row in the DataFrame. So, if you just have one row, I assume it's because you only are passing one list.

Comment: Sorry, my fault....
You're right, i will update the question

I have two lists, from which I suggested that one is a list of lists....
I don't use python that long, I'm still thinking in pascal :D

Comment: This is dp_data: `<class 'list'>: [    Fr  1 Sa  2 So  3 Mo  4 Di  5  ... Di  26 Mi  27 Do  28 Fr  29 Sa  30
0    TO2F  TO2F   NaN   NaN   TO1  ...    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
1     NaN   NaN   NaN   NAN   NaN  ...    NaN    NaN    NaN    TV1    NaN
2     NV1   NaN   NaN   TV1   NV1  ...    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
[115 rows x 30 columns]]`

Comment: As I said, the `dp_data[31:]` is not a list of lists (a matrix), it's just a list so it only will add one row. See the code in my answer, and look at the format of the `rows` variable. You need to pass this format.